# Software & Updates defaults

Tags: default

Is the default setting for version 14.0403 LTS for all to be selected for the "`Ubuntu Software`" tab and for "`Updates`" everything except "`pre release updates` to be selected?

Answer (score 4):

Short Answer: **Yes**

[image: Imageguru]

[image: Imageguru]

These are default settings.